# AWS GLUE Job script to Group by Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I need to pickup latest record for a student ID from CSV file in AWS Glue job and write the same record i CSV or tables
Example:

| StudentID | SQNo |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 100 | 3 |

In above example AWS glue job should pick Student ID 100 and 101 , with ID 100 with SQNo 3 .

its like group by and pickup up max in SQL

trying to convert dynamic frame to data frame but nothing seems to be working for me

Comment: please share the sample code, data and expected output.

Comment: CREATE TABLE #counts
(
    table_name varchar(255),
    row_count int
)

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @command1='INSERT #counts (table_name, row_count) SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*) FROM ?'
SELECT table_name, row_count FROM #counts ORDER BY table_name, row_count DESC
DROP TABLE #counts something like this but in Amazon redshift